# Error transforming the velocity template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I'm using aws-appsync with dynamodb .. I just noticed something:
I used "Scan, filter" to query my data and I want to return an object, 
this is my resolver: `$util.toJson($ctx.result.items[0])`

If the data filtered is not null the data returns successfully, but when the data does not exists,  it returns an error as below:

> "Error transforming the velocity template":

Is there any work-arround to return an object in using "Scan"?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of doing this:

```
#if( ! $ctx.result.items )
  $util.toJson($ctx.result.items[0])
#else
  null ## Or any default value you'd like to return from here
#end
```

You can refer to the [VTL documentation](https://people.apache.org/~henning/velocity/html) for additional information.

AWS AppSync provides [multiple utility methods](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html) in addition to this, so you can use one of the supported utility methods `$util.defaultIfNull(Object, Object) : Object` to achieve the same.

Thanks,
Shankar